# How to write Vietnamese with fourier package(lualatex)?

Tags: fonts

Here is my code, please help me:

```
\documentclass[answers, 11pt, fleqn]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, tmargin=1.5cm, bmargin=2cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,mathtools,tikz}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
Hà Nội là thủ đô
\end{document}
```

Ouput: `Hà Ni là th ô`
I try `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}` but not working. Sorry for my english, please help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no support for Vietnamese in `fourier`.

Comment: I use `fouriernc`. Then, I write 
`\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `fourier` fonts don't cover Vietnamese, but you can use Erewhon (a clone of Utopia) with `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass[answers, 11pt, fleqn]{exam}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper, tmargin=1.5cm, bmargin=2cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsfonts}

\usepackage{fourier} % for math
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % for text
\usepackage{amsthm,tikz}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}

\begin{document}

Hà Nội là thủ đô

$abc+\int_0^t f(t)\,dt=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was new for me. I hadn't realized yet that since the switch to TU `\setmainfont` resets the encoding to TU. But I would nevertheless load fourier (and other packages which perhaps load fontenc) before fontspec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree

Answer (score 0):

I don't use lualatex, then at premable, I use

```
\documentclass[answers, 11pt, fleqn]{exam}
\usepackage{fourier} % for math

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[a4paper, tmargin=1.5cm, bmargin=2cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm,tikz}
\begin{document}
Hà Nội là thủ đô

$abc+\int_0^t f(t)\,dt=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

\end{document}
```

Note that, you must put `\usepackage{fourier}` before `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`
[image]